# How to change the colour of log messages using javahome\logging.properties?

Tags: java

I am using log.info to output my message and they are all red. How do you change the colour by modifying the C:\javahome\logging.properties.

Comment: Also I am using Eclipse as my editor.

Answer (score 1):

The colouring is done by the IDE you are using. Most of the time different log levels (trace, debug, info, warn, error) get different colours, e.g. "error" gets red in most IDEs. Also it might make a difference if the text is output via stdout or stderr, but this depends on your IDE.

Look in the preferences of your IDE for something like console and color. For my IDE IntelliJ the setting can be found under Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Colors. Hope that helps.